# How replace native order by clause on JPA equivalent?

Tags: jpa, subquery, one-to-many

I use JPA 2.0 criteria builder. I need get data from one table and sort them by column from other. This tables have relations OneToMany:

```
 class Club{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "club")
    private List<Address> addresses;
    ...
    }

class Address{
@JoinColumn(name = "club_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Club club;

@Column(name = "type")
private Long type;

@Column(name = "full_address")
    private String full_address;
    ...
        }
```

May be several address of some type but I need only one row of this specific address.

I write native queries with subquery, but it's has problem because subquery doesn't use in order clause and in select clause in JPA 2.0.

```
select c.full_name from club c
  ORDER BY (select a.full_address from address a WHERE c.id= a.club_id and a.type=1 LIMIT 1)


select c.full_name, (select a.full_address from address a WHERE a.type=1 AND c.id=a.club_id LIMIT 1) as full_address FROM club c
ORDER BY fullAddress;
```

How I can replace native order by clause on JPA equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a possibility a club will have many addresses and get placed in the order non-deterministically?  Otherwise, your JPA provider may allow you to use the subquery in the from clause like a table.  But it would likely be better if you modify the query to give you what you want - presumably distinct full_name ordered by address.  Something like "Select c.full_name from club c join c.addresses a where a.type =1 order by a.full_address"

Comment: Thank for you answer. A club can consist several address with type 1 so when using `join` then appear dublicates of club. I need get all club (if exist address with type 1 or no) and sort it.

Comment: Add in a distinct key word, but if type 1 isn't unique, I don't quite understand how you can sort on the non-unique addresses using a subquery either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This native query also resolve problem and it can replace by JPA query

```
select c.full_name, min(a.full_address) FROM club c LEFT JOIN address a on c.id = a.club_id
where a.id is null or a.type=1 or not exists(SELECT  1 from address aSub WHERE aSub .club_id=c.id AND aSub.type=1)
GROUP BY  c.id, c.full_name ORDER BY min(a.full_address);
```

**JPA equivalent**

```
 CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ClubItem> query = builder.createQuery(ClubItem.class);

    Root<Club> root = query.from(Club.class);
    Join<Club, Address> addressJoin = root.join(Club_.address, JoinType.LEFT);

query.select(builder.construct(ClubItem.class, root.get(Club_.id), root.get(Club_.fullName), builder.function("min", String.class, addressJoin.get(Address_.fullAddress))));

    Subquery<Address> subquery = query.subquery(Address.class);
    Root<Address> addressRoot = subquery.from(Address.class);

    subquery.select(addressRoot);
    subquery.where(
            builder.and(
                    builder.equal(addressRoot.get(Address_.type), 1),
                    builder.equal(addressRoot.get(Address_.clubId), root.get(Club_.id))));   

    query.where(builder.or(builder.isNull(addressJoin), builder.equal(addressJoin.get(Address_.type), builder.literal(new Long(1))),
            builder.not(builder.exists(subquery))));

    query.groupBy(root.get(Club_.id), root.get(Club_.fullName))

            Order order = builder.asc(builder.function("min", String.class, addressJoin.get(Address_.fullAddress)));

            query.orderBy(order);            

    TypedQuery<ClubItem> contentQuery = em.createQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not terribly elegant, but it gets the job done...

Make your "Club" class implement Comparable.  Put the order-by logic into the Comparable.  Then use Collections.sort(unsortedList) to get the list into sorted form.   There's also a Collections.sort(unsortedList, Comparable) method which could be useful, especially if you are doing a bunch of similar methods that just vary on order-by.